# How to make nested views on multiple views in angular ui router?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router, nested-views

My app is very simple. i have a home page that contains header and body. in body section I want to show login page and if URL changed to 'password/forget' I show password reset form. my templates:

**index.html** :

```
<header ui-view="header">
</header>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div ui-view="main">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**home.html:**

```
   <div ui-view>
    </div>
```

And ui-router config is this:

```
 $locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true, requireBase: false});
 $stateProvider.state('home', {
     url: '/',
     views: {
       'header': {
         templateUrl: '/header.html'
       },
       'main': {
          templateUrl: '/home.html'
       }
 }
 }).state('home.forgetPassword', {
    url: '/password/forget',
    templateUrl: '/forgetPassword.html',
});
```

Now when I go "/password/forget" anything happen and *index.html* is showing. 
I want to show *forgetPassword.html* when route changes to "/password/forget" .

Comment: When you say you go to `/password/forget`, do you mean `mysite.com/password/forget`, or `mysite.com/#/password/forget`?

Comment: mysite.com/password/forget

Comment: what happens if you visit `mysite.com/#/password/forget`?

Comment: index.html is showing. i updated ui router config and html5mode is appended here however in my code html5mode was enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. it was for `/` in parent state and repeat it on child states.

Answer (score 0):

Following this code in documentation of ui-router:

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('state1', {
      url: "/state1",
      templateUrl: "partials/state1.html"
    })
    .state('state1.list', {
      url: "/list",
      templateUrl: "partials/state1.list.html",
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.items = ["A", "List", "Of", "Items"];
      }
    })
    .state('state2', {
      url: "/state2",
      templateUrl: "partials/state2.html"
    })
    .state('state2.list', {
      url: "/list",
      templateUrl: "partials/state2.list.html",
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.things = ["A", "Set", "Of", "Things"];
      }
    });
});
```

What i suggest is to create the **'password'** state first.

Try the following solution:

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {
     url: '/',
     views: {
       'header': {
         templateUrl: '/header.html'
       },
       'main': {
          templateUrl: '/home.html'
       }
 }
 }).state('password', {
    url: '/password',
    templateUrl: '/password.html',
}).state('password.forgetPassword', {
    url: '/forget',
    templateUrl: '/forgetPassword.html',
});
```

Create the file **'password.html'** for now, later on it might be useful for **'/password'** view.

Comment: I didn't -1 but I think this is an irrelevant answer.